# Relative Paths Visual Studios

Tags: c#, visual-studio, path, relative-path

For school, my group has been tasked with continuing development of a Visual Studio application.  I don't have too much experience with this, as I've only used Visual Basic a few times about 6 years ago.

One of the bugs that I have to fix deals with saving an image to a folder.  When I run the "debug" mode of the code, it saves the image fine.  However if I publish the website using Visual Studios, the page errors because it cannot find the folder.  I cannot hard code the directory, I have to use a relative path.

This is my current code:

```
String path = Server.MapPath("~") + "sig/img.png"
```

This code also works on the debug mode, but not on the publish:

```
String path = Server.MapPath("/") + "sig/img.png"
```

When I try using either System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(path) or System.IO.Path.Combine(basePath, file), it returns a link that starts in ProgramFiles/MicrosoftVisualStudios/

I'm not sure it makes a difference, but all dev work is being done in C:\Users\UserName\program, and it's being published to C:\inetpub\wwwdocs\program

Any help is appreciated.
(One thing that might help is being able to trace the variable "path", but I don't know how to do that once I publish.)

Comment: You could render the path into the page you are attempting to debug. Are you sure this isn't a permissions issue? "the page errors because it cannot find the folder" isn't the best description of what is probably a somewhat more specific error message.

Comment: Agreed with the first commenter.  Show the path (print it in a label, etc.) on the screen to see what you're dealing with.  It'll help for debugging.

Comment: Alright guys, I'm sorry.  You are right on.  It is a permissions issue.  I got it half way there, working when it's from within the network, but once I go remote, it dies, which is farther then I've been.  (Wish I had a CHMOD option on Windows Server...)  Thank-you for your help guys!

Comment: Suggest you mark your question as answered, if you're happy with the solution you found.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new to stackoverflow.com, and I can't seem to find how to mark my question as answered.

Comment: @Michael...not sure you can mark this as answered as, there are technically no "answers" applicable to this question, only comments (which do not count as answers). You can however answer the question yourself, using the information you have received from other users, and then mark this as answered with your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit goes to spender and WLin.  Was a permission error that I overlooked.

Thanks for the help everyone!